# How do I set the area to 0 after the loop has run 1 time?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
a = 0 
b = 2
n = 1
delta_x = (b-a) / n
x = 0
area = 0

def f(x):
    return 1/2*x**2 + 4

while area < 9.333:
    for i in range (0, n):
        area += f(x) * delta_x  
        x += delta_x
    n += 1 # i want to set the area to 0 here so that i can check for what n value area < 9.333
print(n)
```

I tried to set `area = 0` in different places, but it did not work. This code is for checking the area under a function using the left-square method. I want to find out for what n value area < 9.333 in the function `f(x) = 1/2*x**2+4`.

Comment: Im not so good at coding so plaese explain i a basic way

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have to place `area = 0` between `while` and `for`

Comment: You might start by creating a function that calculates the area as a function of a, b, and n, that would help you see the structure more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

As suziex has said you need to assign `area` as 0 between `while` and `for` this way `area` is reset every time `for i in range(0 n)` is run

```
while area < 9.333:
    area = 0
    for i in range (0, n):
        area += f(x) * delta_x  
        x += delta_x
    n += 1
print(n)
```

Comment: But thats prints the answer as n= 3 when the aswer is n = 5997 (i checked it i geogebra)